Leaf parasite/pathogen species identification
What kind/species is this?

Brasília - DF - Brazil (Winter)

These are telia of the telial stage of a pathenogenic fungus called a rust.
I wrote a similar post about the aecia (a defferent reproductive stage) of a similar rust species in the US many years ago here
I'm less familiar with Brazilian organisms, and without a full image of the plant (or more ideally ID of the plant species) or more circumstancial info provided by OP, IDing this particular rust to species would be annoyingly difficult.
Lucky for you, there is a publicly available key (Hennen et al 2005) for Brazilian species (link is PDF):
Catalogue of the species of plant rust fungi (Uredinales) of Brazil.
I encourage you to both update your post with more detail (especially regarding location and type and image of plant) and to start working through they key. After an update, I'd be willing to dive in deeper...
